# Music duplicates on Area-51

Tags: support, area-51

I was wondering if anything can be done about [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/merging-all-music-proposals) on Area51 about music duplicates. Do we wait for administrative intervention or keep creating new sites?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84406/should-we-merge-area-51-proposals-to-attract-more-followers

Comment: A related announcement was posted on the Guitars meta site: http://meta.guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/136/announcement-save-guitars-se-by-supporting-the-music-proposal

Answer (score 4):

Rebecca Chernoff responded on April 4th to say admins are looking into it and will take action soon.